# How to pick contact into edittext using fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, buttonclick, contactpicker

I work with same app I pick my contacts using activities class and it work perfectly now I add same tablayout and fragment I do every possible methods to be solved 
Her is some code

```
public void pickContact(View v)
{
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

It's filld after I build and onclick pickContact button the app stopped working

Comment: post your error log

Answer (score 1):

You need to run time permission first and then.You use activity context to call `startActivityForResult()`.

```
public void pickContact(View v)
{
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    getActivity().startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
}
```

Comment: please send me you crash

Answer (score 0):

i am using this library for contact picker

```
[Multiple contact picker][1]https://github.com/broakenmedia/MultiContactPicker
```